# Swift: Hide a View Controller after first time use

Tags: ios, swift

In swift I am making a app where it asks for a code before going to the actual app. I only want this to be showed once. How do I have this page only showed the first time then they enter the code and they only have to do this once then when they use the app again they don't need to enter a code. Thanks.

Comment: You can create `if-else` conditions with different viewcontrollers or xibs. Once the app has launched, or say user has logged in (In this case check the login token to present the controller) you can check for a BOOL set using `NSUserDefaults` and present the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best shot is `NSUserDefaults`. Save a flag (a boolean) in `NSUserDefaults` to indicate whether it is the first time the user has opened the app.

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if userDefaults.valueForKey("IS_FIRST_TIME") as? Bool != nil {
    // First time, do something...
    // ...
    // ...
    // Now, save a flag to indicate that this was the first time.
    userDefaults.setValue(true, forKey: "IS_FIRST_TIME")
    userDefaults.synchronize()  // Needed to save the new value.
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code you can show me to do this? Thanks so much! :D